# How to load native lib in android with static{System.loadLibrary()}

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I was studying the android source code and I found that there are many places in framework that use native code without using static{System.loadLibrary()}.

For example, in SystemServer.java, native method "init1(args)" is called but there is no static{System.loadLibrary()} in the file. How native code is loaded without static{System.loadLibrary()}? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The native library has to be loaded only once for the whole application, so it has probably already been loaded by another class which has been instantiated before. Note that this is not a best practice as it makes assumptions on the order by which the classes are called!

A commonly used technic to avoid this is to create a `Loader` class like this:

```
class Loader {
    private static boolean done = false;

    protected static synchronized void load() {
        if (done)
            return;

        System.loadLibrary("library_name");

        done = true;
    }
}
```

This way, if you call `static{Loader.load();}` on every class that requires the use of native functions, you ensure that the library has been loaded (and only once).